# What is the mounted value and how does it work?

Tags: flutter, dart

What does this `mounted` value do? Without the `if (!mounted) return;` there will be warning `Do not use BuildContexts across async gaps`. But how does it actually work?

What does the signature mean `build(BuildContext context, [bool mounted = true])`? Why the `mounted` is in the square brackets here?

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, [bool mounted = true]) {
    return PopupMenuButton<MenuAction>(
      onSelected: (value) async {
        switch (value) {
          case MenuAction.logout:
            final shouldLogOut = await showLogOutDialog(context);
            if (!mounted) return;
            if (shouldLogOut) {
              context.read<AppState>().logOut();
            }
            ...
```

Comment: The [] syntax means that "mounted" is an "optional parameter".  It's of type "boolean", with a default value of "true". Look here for an explanation of Dart [optional parameters](https://zaiste.net/posts/dart-optional-function-parameters/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `widget` is `mounted` if it has `state`. If the widget is no longer `mounted`, i.e it has been closed or `disposed`, its `state` can no longer be updated. Therefore, we check if a `widget` is `mounted` to determine if its `state` can still be updated.

In more simple words if **mounted** is true the widget is visible on screen else it is **disposed**.

Answer (score 2):

> What does the signature mean build(BuildContext context, [bool mounted = true])? Why the mounted is in the square brackets here?

Square brackets in the signature of a function or constructor simply mean that the arguments inside it are optional.